# Red5 java error on startup

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, red5

When I started red5 I got the following error message;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.red5.server.Launcher
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
at org.red5.server.Bootstrap.bootStrap(Bootstrap.java:115)
at org.red5.server.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:48)
```

Please help I need this to start up again quickly.

Running Ubuntu and red5 1.0.0

Comment: Did you add required jar to your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://code.google.com/p/red5/wiki/ServerWontStart

> ClassNotFoundException Launcher
>
> When the Launcher cannot be located, it usually means the server jar
>   is missing or misnamed. The Red5 server jar must be named like so
>   until we fix the bootstrap bug: red5-server-1.0.jar